# Group cohomology of fundamental group and singular cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences

Let $X$ be a nice complex variety and fix a basepoint $x_0$. Denote $\pi:=\pi_1(X,x_0)$. Let $\mathbb{V}$ be a local system on $X$, and consider the cohomology groups $H^i(\pi, \mathbb{V}_{x_0}), H^i(X,\mathbb{V})$. Clearly, they are isomorphic for $i=0$.

I heard that there is a Leray spectral sequence that computes the group cohomologies using the singular cohomologies, and that it gives a map from the $i$'th singular ones to the $i'th$ group ones. Does anyone know how to construct this map? When is it injective?

Comment: In general, if you have a group $G$ and a $G$-module $M$, then you can consider the classifying space $BG$ and the $G$-module $M$ defines a system of local coefficients on $BG$. Then, we have that $H^{\ast}(G,M)=H^{\ast}(BG,M)$, so group cohomology is translated into singular cohomology. I believe (though this is without guarantee) that the local system of coefficients on $X$ induces a $\pi$-principal bundle that is classified by a (homotopy class of a) map $X\rightarrow B\pi$, which is compatible with the respective local coefficient systems and hence induces the comparison map on cohomlogy.